# Wagtail API - show image URL on json output

Tags: django, wagtail

Fairly new to Wagtail - I'm currently creating a Wagtail API for my React app. Have installed successfully and am getting a json output, but not getting a url for images that are uploaded in the Wagtail admin panel. I have searched online, but not having much joy.

This is the basic home page model I have created

```
class BarsHomePage(Previewable, Themable, Page):

    bars_site_homepage_test = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    feed_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'DemoImage',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )



    api_fields = ['bars_site_homepage_test','feed_image']

class DemoImage(Image):
    @property
    def fullwidth_url(self):
        return generate_image_url(self, 'width-800')

    @property
    def halfwidth_url(self):
        return generate_image_url(self, 'width-400')

    api_fields = (
        'fullwidth_url',
        'halfwidth_url',
    )

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Json output

```
{
    "id": 504,
    "meta": {
        "type": "wagtailimages.Image",
        "detail_url": "http://www.lv.local/api/v1/images/504/"
    },
    "title": "Lighthouse.jpg",
    "tags": [],
    "width": 1365,
    "height": 2048
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show your DemoImage model and json output?

Comment: Have edited above - excuse the bad formatting....

Answer (score 2):

As of Wagtail 1.10, you can use [ImageRenditionField](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10.1/advanced_topics/api/v2/configuration.html#images-in-the-api) in your page's `api_fields` definition to include the URL for an image, rendered at a size of your choosing:

```
from wagtail.api import APIField
from wagtail.wagtailimages.api.fields import ImageRenditionField

class BarsHomePage(Previewable, Themable, Page):
    # ...

    api_fields = [
        APIField('bars_site_homepage_test'),
        APIField('feed_image_fullwidth', serializer=ImageRenditionField('width-800', source='feed_image')),
    ]
```